# Set date range for lineItem using GoogleAds API

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have been having trouble trying to figure out how to set a range of dates for a given lineItem using the google ads php client library. Basically, what I want to do is make a line item to be available for a specified start date and an end date but no success. In [their example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdManager/v202111/LineItemService/CreateLineItemsWithCustomCriteria.php) they have this snippet:

```
$lineItem->setStartDateTimeType(StartDateTimeType::IMMEDIATELY);
$lineItem->setEndDateTime(
            AdManagerDateTimes::fromDateTime(
                new DateTime('+1 month', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'))
            )
        );
```

They're setting a start date for the line item to IMMEDIATELY, and and end date to 1 month from the time of creation. I tried passing to AdManagerDateTimes::fromDateTimeString a valid ISO 8601 string and no luck (GAM spits an error). Tried creating a DateTime() instance and passing it to the code above, nothing. I'm not too experienced in php and maybe this is way easier than i think it is but I'm stuck.

Any tips please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you already solve this issue, but you can change in the new DateTime include the date you want

```
$lineItem->setEndDateTime(
  AdManagerDateTimes::fromDateTime(
    new DateTime('2023-02-12')
  )
);
```